# Google Play Store Error DF-BPA-30

Tags: android, google-play

I'm getting a error on Play Store with my Motorola Moto G. I'm unable to purchase any app. I always get the DF-BPA-30 error. Someone can help-me please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on a network that you control?  I have been on networks before that block access to the Google Play Store such as here at the work site.  So I was always unable to download via wifi, but over the data plan it worked ok.  I assume since you say Moto G however, that you aren't trying this only on wifi.  Unless you haven't activated it yet or its a development phone.

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm at work and my colleague can download apps on its moto x. I believe that it is not the problem.

Comment: It is possible that you might need to do a reset on your Google Play Services app.  When tunneling between different countries to test installations or downloads there, occasionally you might need to clear the data and cache for the app.  Or go into the Google Play Services Framework app and clear data there.

Comment: Clearing cache and data from Google Play Services solved this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fix it is remove the Google accounts of the phone, then cancel all syncs. Then sign back into your Google account and sync. The problem should be solved.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it for me. The problem started after rooting my Galax Note 3 N9005.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same issue. Ultimately I got the solution. It was because of time synchronization issue. Follow these simple steps to resolve the issue.

1. Go to Settings->Date & Time
2. Uncheck the two boxes which say "Automatic date & time" and "Automatic time zone"
3. You will now be allowed to set date manually. Change the date to anything in past. For example, just change the year to 2010 or 2012
4. Come to home screen
5. Again to Settings-> Date & Time
6. Now check both the boxes you unchecked earlier
7. Time would be automatically updated and "Set time" filed would be disabled now
8. Try downloading the app from Play Store

Ref : [Fix "Error Processing Purchase [DF-BPA-30]" on Android Play Store](http://www.techvigil.com/tips-tricks/397/error-processing-purchase-df-bpa-30/)

Comment: this did not work - appears could be something on googles side and time is what usually fixes this (as in wait for google)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug coming from Google's side from what i have understood.

The next article covers it  : http://www.technipages.com/google-play-error-processing-purchase

You can also indeed follow the steps suggested by bijang and see if they work out for you.